# XML Schema: Datatype (text datatype)

Tags: types, xsd

I know that when you write characters you use string. However, is there a datatype called text? This is because my assignment has things like:

X is in type text
Y is in type string

so I was wondering whether there is any other datatype for text other than string

Comment: Could you show the schema for types `X` and `Y` that you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard data type `text` in XML schemas (XSD) - see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#built-in-datatypes). Of course you can define one based on string:

```
<xs:simpleType name="text">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    . . . some restriction . . .
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

but I suspect that this is not what you mean.